How to set a config property after Quarkus app is built?
I am trying to implement an integration test for my Quarkus app where I use Test Container and Azurite to instantiate a blob container. Now when the container is started I can build the connection string using the port that the container is mapped to on my host.
The problem is that the Quarkus app is then already built and I'm having trouble updating the config property for the connection string.
Does anyone know how to do this?
@Singleton
public class BlobStorageTestResource implements QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager {

    @Container
    final GenericContainer azurite = new GenericContainer(DockerImageName.parse("mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite"))
            .withExposedPorts(10000)
            .withCommand("azurite-blob --blobHost 0.0.0.0 --blobPort 10000 --loose");

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> start() {
        azurite.start();

        String connectionString = String.format("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:%d/devstoreaccount1;", azurite.getFirstMappedPort());

        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
                .connectionString(connectionString)
                .buildClient();

        blobServiceClient.createBlobContainer("conversion");

        return Map.of();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        azurite.stop();
    }
}

    @Produces
    @Singleton
    @IfBuildProfile("test")
    BlobContainerAsyncClient provideTestBlobContainer() {
        return new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
                .connectionString(blobConfig.connectionString())
                .buildAsyncClient()
                .getBlobContainerAsyncClient(blobConfig.containerName());
    }


Are you talking about a @QuarkusIntegraionTest? If so: method start() should return a map with an entry <key-for-connection-string>, <connection-string>. The property should then be automatically injected into the application under test.

You should check smallrye ConfigSourceFactory if you want to inject configuration before app is built.
https://quarkus.io/guides/config-extending-support#config-source-factory
Quarkus configuration relies on smallrye implementation of microprofile, so their doc provides more ways when it comes to dealing with programatic configuration injection.
https://smallrye.io/smallrye-config/Main/config-sources/custom/#configsourcefactory
Then you can just create your bean once the correct configuration is provided, and use @ConfigProperty

For future reference:
I already had a default value in the application.properties file in my test resources. This was being used upon start of the Quarkus app.
I had to set that specific property in the map returning from the start() method of my test resource. So something like the following:
return Map.of("%test.azure.storage.blob.connection-string", connectionString);

Now the constructed connection string will be correctly set in my test properties.
